# How to ensure account passed to anchor is readonly but initialized

Tags: anchor, security

So just wanted a confirmation, i know init will check this and if its initialized it will error out, but what is the opposite of init check, i.e check the account passed is initialized ?
does anchor automatically checks for initialization, if the type of the account is not AccountInfo but in form of the Account<'info,T> wrapper ?
so if i do

````
``` 
#[derive(Accounts)
pub struct check<'info> {
test_initialization : Account<'info,test>
}
#[account]
pub test {
x : u32;
}```
````

can my program assume the account "test_initialization" was initialized in the above code snippet if it reaches the business logic side of it ?

Comment: is the Account<'info,T> wrapper implicit check enough , or I should add a initialized field and check it for instructions where i want the account to be initialized ? but i think this wont be necessary if the account wrapper works as i anticipate just need confirmation.

Comment: So long as you don't add the`mut` constraint, the account will be read only

Answer (score 2):

There's no explicit check needed here. As long as there's no init, zero or zero_copy attribute for the account, the validator expects it to have been created. The answer to your question is yes, the program assumes the account is initialized and infact throws an error if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by "initialised".

`AccountInfo` is, for all intent and purposes, unchecked. When using the `Account` wrapper though, the following gets checked:

- Check that the account has some lamports. Otherwise, throw `AccountNotInitialized`.
- Check if the account discriminator in the first 8 bytes of account data exists and matches the program. Otherwise, throw `AccountDiscriminatorNotFound` and `AccountDiscriminatorMismatch` respectively.
- Finally, parse the account using `AnchorDeserialize::deserialize`. If failed, throw `AccountDidNotDeserialize`

Most of this logic is sprinkled around these parts of the source code if you want to dig deeper:

- https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/src/accounts
- https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/lang/attribute/account/src

Comment: there is a check for initialization too i believe as init errors out if the account is already initialized , how does it check for it ? by checking the discriminator and giving the custom error "account already initialized " ? would clear it out if its refrence can be found on the codebase to see what does it do.

Comment: By initialization i mean,  init has been called on the account, by a different anchor instruction

Comment: Do you mean `AccountDiscriminatorAlreadySet`? That one is thrown if the first 8 bytes of the account are not empty (0).

Comment: wait i think its called Expected Account to be already initialized or smth

Comment: That's `AccountNotInitialized` (my first bullet point): https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/205e9d875f9abf1fc379cfc8114c5c53f0207141/lang/src/error.rs#L170

Comment: So what i was doing was , keeping a initialized variable setting it true upon initialization, but if anchor already checks for the discriminator and owner check while deserializing it seemed redundant, just wanted to be sure am not leaving any gap by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

In general `Anchor` assumes it's initialized, if you're using `UncheckedAccount` or similar , can use the following.
(unless `init` is provided)

```
pub fn assert_initialized<T: Pack + IsInitialized>(
    account_info: &AccountInfo,
) -> Result<T, ProgramError> {
    let account: T = T::unpack_unchecked(&account_info.data.borrow())?;
    if !account.is_initialized() {
        Err(ErrorCode::UninitializedAccount.into())
    } else {
        Ok(account)
    }
}
```

Lifted off:

https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/e057c72645b32a5b3776a6a93e33440e719a0ddd/auction-house/program/src/utils.rs#L249-L256